# I want to import my states legislation into a database. I need advice in parsing large HTML, TXT into an importable form. It is Large PDF initialy

Tags: classification, dataset, data-mining, data-cleaning, parsing

My data consists of large pdf files containing state legislation. I can convert the pdf to xml, txt or html, and I can manually go through, identify the tables and write a script to extract only the laws and there relations etc.

But I'm not hugely experienced, and I was wondering if there were tools or tips that might put me on a better track.

I couldn't import the html files into ms sql, or mysql, even though I tried converting/saving it as straight text, as an aside. Anyway, anything to point me right would be appreciated.

Has anyone heard of someone making a project of loading relevant information from a states legislation into a db ... I was wanting to experiment with ML, chatGTP etc. on it.

Comment: If i understood correctly your question then i think you can use **ChatGPT** API with **prompt engineering** to to read texts and classify it or extract some info from it,